# How I can solve this inequality $(R\gamma^T(1/(1−\gamma))≤\epsilon)$ for $T$?!

Tags: inequality

Can someone solve this inequality for $T$

$$
R\gamma^T(1/(1−\gamma))≤\epsilon
$$
In a paper it solved for $T$ and the inequation below is the result, but I can not prove how the inequation above can be the inequation below: 
$$
T≥(1/(1−\gamma))\log⁡(R/(\epsilon(1−\gamma)))
$$
May someone help me,

thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are $\;\gamma, R, \epsilon...\;$ ? Real numbers, positive, perhaps $\;0<\gamma<1\;$ ?

Comment: All are real numbers, and $0<\epsilon,\gamma<1$!
Thancks for your comment @Timbuc

Comment: @So Are you asking *me*?!

Comment: Sorry! I edited my previous comment

Comment: I think *also* $\;R>0\;$ , otherwise the inequality is trivially true for all $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: I also think it is true, but I can not prove and show it with some steps!

Comment: @S0H31L Are you sure of your inequality? Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I have checked them, they same as in the paper
Your can see them in page 8 and 9 of this paper http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/reinforcement.pdf

Comment: The inequality you give for $\;T\;$ is *an assumption* in page 8 of that paper, @S0H31L

Comment: @S0H31L Yes, this is an hypothesis.

Comment: @Timbuc see page 9, there is the proof of that assumption

Comment: @S0H31L Probably a typo.

Comment: @OlivierOloa oh no, this is a great and highly cited paper in machine learning!

Comment: @S0H31L Ok, maybe it would be better to ask Michael Kearns about it. I did my best on my answer below, with all basic steps :)

Comment: Thank you @OlivierOloa, you helped a lot. I think a combination of your assumption ($1-\gamma≥log\gamma$) and and Timbuc's answer (replacing $log\gamma$ with $1-\gamma$) can solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19717/discussion-between-s0h31l-and-olivier-oloa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $0<\gamma<1$, $R>0$, $\epsilon>0$. We multiply both sides of
$$
R\gamma^T(1/(1−\gamma))≤\epsilon
$$ by the **positive** real number $\displaystyle (1−\gamma)/R$ to get
$$
\gamma^T \leq\epsilon(1−\gamma)/R
$$ since $\displaystyle (\infty,0) \ni x \mapsto \log x$ is an **increasing** function we get
$$
T \log \gamma \leq \log \left(\epsilon(1−\gamma)/R \right) 
$$ equivalently
$$
-T \log \gamma \geq \log \left(R/(\epsilon(1−\gamma)) \right) 
$$ but **how** to get the desired inequality since **we know that** $1-\gamma \geq \log \gamma$, $0<\gamma<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything has the correct value (i.e., all is positive and $\;0<\gamma <1\;$):

$$R\gamma^t\frac1{1-\gamma}\le\epsilon\implies \gamma^t\le\frac{\epsilon(1-\gamma)}R\implies t\log\gamma\le\log\frac{\epsilon(1-\gamma)}R\implies$$

$$t\ge\frac{\log\frac{\epsilon(1-\gamma)}R}{\log\gamma}\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;\log\gamma<0$$

I've no idea how in that paper they got the inequality you give for $\;t\;$ .

Comment: I think using the assumption in @Olivier's answer we can replace $log\gamma$ with $1-\gamma$, may you confirm it?

Comment: @S0H31L I can't see how could you do that, but it is *not* only that: the other logarithm's argument is upside down.

Comment: oh no! you are right! :s
tnx!